# django form.errors in template

Tags: python, django, templates

I need your help. 
Problem: I have a template, view and form for create new user, and if I make same error in my registration (example: password1 != password2), I should see the error in my template, but they are not.
SOS!

views:

```
def registration(request):
if request.method == "POST" :
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        print "form is valid"
        form.save()
        return render_to_response("action_succes.html")
    else:
        print form.is_valid()
        print form.errors
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))
form = UserCreationForm()
#args["form"] = UserCreationForm()
#return render_to_response("registration.html", args)
return render(request, "registration.html", {'form':form})
```

model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='Email address',
    max_length=45,
    unique=True,
    db_index=True,
)
username = models.TextField(verbose_name='Nick', max_length=15, unique=True)
profession = models.TextField(verbose_name='Profession', max_length=15)
avatar = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True, null=True)
profile_vkontakte = models.TextField(verbose_name='Profile in vkontakte', max_length=10, null=True)
coordinate_x = models.FloatField(verbose_name='X', null=True)
coordinate_y = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Y', null=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = UserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

def get_full_name(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name,)

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.username

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.email

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_admin
```

template:

```
<form action="registration" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{%csrf_token%}
<label for="id_email">Email</label><br>
{{form.email}}<br>
<label for="id_username">Username</label><br>
{{form.username}}<br>
<label for="id_profession">Profession</label><br>
{{form.profession}}<br>
<label for="id_avatar">Avatar</label><br>
{{form.avatar}}<br>
<label for="id_password1">Password</label><br>
{{form.password1}}<br>
<label for="id_password2">Password (confirm)</label><br>
{{form.password2}}<br>
<label for="id_profile_vkontakte">Vkontakte ID: </label><br>
{{ form.profile_vkontakte }}<br>
<br><br>
Choice you current location:<br>
<label for="id_coordinate_x">X: </label><br>
{{ form.coordinate_x }}<br>
<label for="id_coordinate_y">Y: </label><br>
{{ form.coordinate_y }}<br>
{% for i in form.errors %}
{{i}}
{% endfor %}
{% if form.errors %}
error!
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="Register"/><br>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have assigned; `form = UserCreationForm()` more number of times than required.

It should be:

```
if request.method == "POST" :
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES) #since request.POST is present, populate the form with POST values
    if form.is_valid(): #Check if its valid
       print "form is valid"
       form.save()
       return render_to_response("action_succes.html")
    else: #invalid case
        print form.is_valid()   #form contains data and errors
        print form.errors
else:
    form = UserCreationForm() #No post data

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))
return render(request, "registration.html", {'form':form}) # Sending the form to view
```