# Displaying forms.ValidationError on the same template

Tags: python, django, forms, templates

```
def clean(self):
        ......
        if reason == choice.MISTAKE:
            if message == "":
                raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required") 
        return data
```

How do I show this validation error on the template? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291192/django-form-errors-in-template)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/